# Playing a featured video on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need a option for my wordpress page to play a featured video (just like a featured image) on hover and when the mouse leaves the container to make stop the video.

Something like on this link, just not on text hover but on video container hover.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/pNbYq/4/`
```

I need to make a video play without sound option. So that you have a little icon in the right upper edge that activates the sound.

The best solution for me would be if somebody could make something like on www.vine.co that player is just perfect.

I want to have the same option on my site.

I hope that somebody can help me out . Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/pNbYq/146/

```
<div id="video-holder">
    <div id="video1-container">
        <video id="video1" muted>
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
        <div class="volume-controller" id="audio-ctrl"> <i class="fa fa-volume-up" id="volume-on"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-volume-off" id="volume-off"></i>

        </div>
    </div>
    <video id="video2">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <video id="video3">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="button-holder">    <a data-video="video1">Video 1</a>
    <a data-video="video2">Video 2</a>
    <a data-video="video3">Video 3</a>

</div>

$('#audio-ctrl').click(function () {
    var sound = $('#video1').prop('muted');
    if (sound) {
        $('#video1').prop('muted', false);
        $('#volume-off').hide();
        $('#volume-on').show();
    } else {
        $('#video1').prop('muted', true);
        $('#volume-on').hide();
        $('#volume-off').show();
    }
});

$('#video1-container').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('#video1').get(0).play();
});
$('#video1-container').on('mouseout', function () {
    $('#video1').get(0).pause();
});

#video2, #video3 {
    display:none;
}
a:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.volume-controller {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
#volume-on {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend thats almost it , can the sound just be muted when you you hover over it, so that you need to click on the icon to play the sound, that would be great, and thank you very much that helped me out a lot.